# Loop a specfic range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

can anyone explain to me the proper way to loop a certain range? I do not understand this part on how to make this work please? How do I do this only from row 2 to 4? It has a compile error, loop without for, any idea how to amend this please

```
Sub send_mass_email_display_only()

Dim i As Integer
Dim name As String, email As String, body As String, subject As String, copy As String, pdfadd As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object


body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text


For i = 2 To 4
'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    
    name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0)
    'name = Cells(i, 1).Value
    email = Cells(i, 2).Value
    subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
    copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
    pdfadd = Cells(i, 5).Value
    
    body = Replace(body, "C1", name)

    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
         .To = email
         .cc = copy
         .subject = subject
         .body = body
         .Attachments.Add (pdfadd)
         .display
         '.Send
    End With

    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text 'reset body text
    
    Next i


Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"

End Sub
```

Comment: You already wrote `For i = 2 To 4`, so whats problem in that range ?

Comment: It comes out with a compile error "next without for", I am not sure how to properly write this as i am new to VBA, can you assist pls? Thanks

Comment: I don't see `Loop` that ends the `Do While` statement.

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz How should I write this Sir to make it work? Thanks

Comment: You just need to put word `Loop` one line before `Next i`. Please see examples: [example1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_do_while_loop.htm), [example2](https://excelchamps.com/vba/do-while)

Comment: While adding `Loop` as suggested will fix the syntax error,  it won't make the code work as intended.   What is probably required is to replace the `Do While` with an `If`

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz I put the word Loop one line before Next i, the programme looped indefinitely haha

Comment: offcouse `Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""` states that keep on loop till `Value` is not empty.

Comment: I think you should replace `Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""` with `If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Continue For`. This will skip empty values. and also remove `Loop`

Comment: Please, try simple delete/comment the line `Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""`. And `Loop`, of course. The code has been designed to loop until the first empty cell, but if you loop only in the first 4 rows, `Do   Loop` it is not necessary, anymore... If it worked before, this means that no empty cells in the range you need iterating. So, no need to check if `Cells(i, 1).Value = ""`.

Comment: Ok now I am more confused how to write it :'D

Answer (score 0):

I tried as FaneDuru/grayProgrammerz suggested to delete the Do While line... seems that this works so far

```
Option Explicit

Sub send_mass_email_display_only()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name As String, email As String, body As String, subject As String, copy As String, pdfadd As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    
    For i = 2 To 4
    'Specific rows
        
        name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0)
        'name = Cells(i, 1).Value
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        pdfadd = Cells(i, 5).Value
        
        body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
    
        
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .To = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             .body = body
             .Attachments.Add (pdfadd)
             .display
             '.Send
        End With
    
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text 'reset body text
        
        
        Next i
    
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    'MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @J Ng What "so far" should mean? It will fail only if not appropriate values would exist in the processed range. Which would behave the same in the original version. You could also keep the original version but exiting the loop after 4 iterations. `Do While i <= 4` then existing code, but before `Loop` place `i = i + 1`, to increment the variable. Which probably existed already... Or let the code exactly as it was, but insert the next line before variable incrementation: `if i = 4 Then Exit Do`.